# How to upload blob file to server, store and get the file to client side back

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I'm using React.js for client side and Node.js for server side.

I upload an image file through `<input type="file"/>` and It will be cropped as soon as its uploaded.

the type of cropped image file is `blob` which looks like `blob:http://localhost:3011/bf45efc1-06d0-4374-ac56-04d05e51f02c`.

I'd like to store the blob file in database(column type BLOB) and get the blob file to the client side from database to show the image on the client side. (or If you have a better way to store the file, please tell me)

so, Let's say I have a blob file that i got from database and it looks like `blob:http://localhost:3011/bf45efc1-06d0-4374-ac56-04d05e51f02c` and I'd like to show this file on the client side. How do I do it?

I'm also curious what `http://localhost:3011` does. I know that means I uploaded that file on the localhost. but does it mean I can't get proper image data when im on a different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing the file on disk on the server side, then saving the name or path of the file to a database. The file saved on disk can be saved in a directory accessible by Apache (httpd), then the users can simply access the files by accessing the Apache host url e.g. http://something.com/images/savedimageuuid.png

Comment: yeah but still I wanna to save the file in database, get the file to clientside and display on `<img src={}/>` for some reason...